# "awk" is not processing shell variables as expected

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I am working on filtering Specific text from a log file. Problem here is that awk is not processing on shell variable. But working fine on filename. 
I am storing a new log entry that comes in log file in a shell variable using "new_log=tail -n5 alerts.log" in a loop whenever a new log comes, then ,

```
Level_no=`awk '{FS="Rule: "}{print $2}' "$new_log" | sed '/^$/d' | awk '{FS=" "}{print $3}' | sed 's/)//g'
```

Output:

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `** Alert 1564460779.1380: mail  - ossec,syscheck
* New Log starts from ** Alert 1564460779.1380: mail  - ossec,syscheck *`
```

Above mentioned command works well when I run it in terminal using filename instead of shell variable as follows:

```
awk '{FS="Rule: "}{print $2}' logs_mining | sed '/^$/d' | awk '{FS=" "}{print $3}' | sed 's/)//g'
```

But its performance issue if I store new log entry in another file and process from there.

So I researched more and more and came to know about awk variables...here is my shell script..

```
Level_no=`awk -v var="$new_log" '{FS="Rule: "}{print $2}' var | sed '/^$/d' | awk '{FS=" "}{print $3}' | sed 's/)//g'
```

Then output says

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `var' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Actual Result should be Successful execution of awk script.

Comment: What contains `$new_log`? Can you give us the result of `echo "$new_log"`?

Comment: The second argument to `awk` is a filename, but `$new_log` doesn't contain a filename, it contains the lines you extracted from the file.

Comment: @MuhammadShayaan : Aside from the fact that in your first attempt, `new_file`  did **not** contain what you posted it does (as we can see from the error message), even if it would contain `tail -n5 alerts.log` as you said, I doubt that you have a file of this name. I suggest that you run your code under `set -x`.  BTW, your command is lacking a closing backquote. And: Backquotes are obsolete; it is recommended to use `$(...)` instead.

Comment: You are right. @Barmar $new_log contains the lines extracted from the file

Comment: `awk '{FS="Rule: "}{...}'` sets FS **after** it's already been used with it's default value on the first record. I suspect you wanted `awk 'BEGIN{FS="Rule: "}{...}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `new_log` contains the data you want to process, not a filename, you need to pipe it to `awk`. You can do this with a here-string.

```
Level_no=`awk '{FS="Rule: "}{print $2}' <<<"$new_log" | sed '/^$/d' | awk '{FS=" "}{print $3}' | sed 's/)//g'`
```

It's also not necessary to pipe the output to `sed` and another `awk`, you can do it all in the first script.

```
Level_no=$(awk -F'Rule: ' '$2 != "" {split($2, a, " "); gsub(/)/, "", a[3]); print a[3]}' <<<"$new_log")
```

You probably don't need the variable, though, just pipe the output of the command to awk:

```
Level_no=$(tail -n5 alerts.log | awk -F'Rule: ' '$2 != "" {split($2, a, " "); gsub(/)/, "", a[3]); print a[3]}')
```

Comment: Though a much better solution is to not have the input in a variable.

Comment: Good piont, added a variant that removes the variable.

Comment: That Worked Excellently...Thanks a lot. @Barmar